# Unknown padding on the right side of left scroll div in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a table with some contents. The contents increase on button click. I have managed to add scroll on the right side when overflowed. Everything works fine. When i change the scroll to left side there is an unknown padding on the right side of the div `outer-wrapper`. The issue is seen only when inspecting and hover over the dom element. The issue is only in chrome. I have tested with mozilla and it's working.

```
<div class="test-container">
  <div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td class="content-box">
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="click-me">
  Click Me to Fill
  </button>
</div>
```

The issue is with `outer-wrapper`. It shows unknown extension to right on inspecting.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/yr9mok3h/25/)

Here is the screenshot of issue 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overflow-y: overlay;` - This only works on WebKit browsers, This means that the viewport will have the same width without scroll

```js
$('#click-me').click(function(){
 $('.table .content-box').append('<p>test</p>');
});
```

```css
.test-container{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid lightgray;
  height:530px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.outer-wrapper{
  border:1px solid lightgray;
  height:530px;
  width:320px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-y:overlay;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  direction:rtl;
}
.inner-wrapper{
  width:290px;
  direction:ltr;
  /* border:1px solid yellow; */
}
button{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:10px;
  /* text-align:right; */
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-container">
  <div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td class="content-box">
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="click-me">
  Click Me to Fill
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working. But i need it to work in all browsers. Can you make your answer compatible with all browsers ?

Comment: `overlay` is non-standard value and hence i am not willing to use it unless there is a standard solution

Comment: Okay, i already updated with overflow:auto and overflow:overlay and i am finding other solution also

Comment: overflow auto doesn't remove issue

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. If you can give me a solution other than with `overlay` i will accept your answer

Comment: There is another solution using ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none; 
} bot it hides scrollbar and you can scroll also

Comment: I need scrollbar

Comment: using both `overflow:auto` and `overflow:overlay` works fine in all browsers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you change direction on outer-wrapper from rtl to ltr, it seems to fix the issue.

Is it possible the issue is caused by inconsistent rtl/ltr?

Comment: I need scroll on left side. So i changed direction in outer-wrapper to rtl